# licensing requirements to use PREMIUM connector when calling workflow after adding SharePoint item

Tags: office-365, power-automate, flow, licensing, power-platform

We want to create a workflow which use this Premium action:

[image]

The workflow will run as an automated flow when a SharePoint custom list item is created >> where the workflow will create a document based on a template.

Now the creator of the workflow already has a Premium license, but the users who will add the SharePoint custom list item and use the generated documents do not have premium license, so does this violate Microsoft licensing and can be considered as multiplexing?

Comment: Hi @microsoftdeveloperdesigner, does my below response answers your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any issue with using premium license for only flow owner (or system account) only.

As your Power automate flow will run with connections of flow owner only, having premium license to only flow owner (or system account) is enough for such requirements.

Note, all the actions for this connector will run using the flow owner. So, for example, if you are creating the files again in SharePoint, the name in Created By field will be set to flow owner by default.